# So Android compatibility libraries are not just for compatibility?

Tags: android

When I hear the name "compatibility library", it sounds like something that I would use if I want to make my app compatible with something.  Each Android compatibility library has an API level associated with it, e.g. "7".  This evidently means that I can build against API level 24 but ensure that the app can be run on anything way back to 7.

This makes sense to me.

However, it seems that these "compatibility libraries" also contain features that are not available elsewhere, even in Android itself.  For example DrawerLayout is something found in support-v4 but evidently nowhere else.  This means that you can set your minSdkVersion to "15" but you still need to declare support-v4 as a dependency if you want to use DrawerLayout even though you don't need compatibility way back to API level 4.

However, I haven't been able to find anything that states this explicitly.  Have I read between the lines correctly, or is there something I am not getting?

Comment: You understand correctly. It's a thing where it started out as a compatibility library and evolved into much more. The key distinction is that the support libraries you use are packaged within your APK file, while the core SDK library is taken from the device. So the compatibility library gets you API stability across devices.

Comment: Also worth mentioning - The AppCompat-v7 transitively depends on Support v4 and the Design library transitively depends on AppCompat-v7

Comment: Note that they have been called the Android Support libraries for a few years now, partly for this reason. They have never been purely for "compatability" purposes. Also note that as of 24.2.0, `support-v4` [has been subdivided into smaller libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-v4-refactor), to make it easier for you to request only the bits that you need. Transitive dependencies may cause you to get more than you expect, though.

Comment: To those who have marked this as a duplicate:  The cited question is about support-v4 specifically but my question is more general and not only about support-v4. I use support-v4 as an _example_ and also mention api level 7.  I don't know the rules around what constitutes a duplicate.  Are people supposed to infer that the Android conventions are the same for all other support libraries?  If so, on what basis?  I did spend time searching for a similar question but didn't find anything similar.  BTW, I don't know of any other way to question duplicate claims so beg pardon if this is bad form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic understanding of the Android support libraries is correct. The libraries are intended for backwards compatibility. However, Android can introduce new features in the support libraries that aren't in the core framework. Android uses this because every device is slightly different, and therefore apps look different on different devices. (You can easily see an example, run ConnectBot on Android 2.3 and 4.1, or any two versions that look significantly different). The support libraries try to help unify the experience across all devices.

I hope this answers your question.